# Angular 2 lazy loading redirecting to a blank page

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I changed my angular 2 scripts and created a new feature module that contain component of signup and signin pages:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { NotfoundComponent } from '../notfound/notfound.component';
import { ChildRoutingModule } from './auth.route';
@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        SignupComponent,
        SigninComponent,
        NotfoundComponent
    ],

    imports:[
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,

        ChildRoutingModule
    ]
})

export class AuthModule{}
```

And of course I created a child route file called `ChildRoutingModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';

const childRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'signup', loadChildren: './auth.module#AuthModule'},
    {path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes)
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class ChildRoutingModule { }
```

In this routes file, I created a lazy loading to home page by using:

```
{path: 'signup', loadChildren: './auth.module#AuthModule'},
```

as you see it at the AuthModule exported class.

Here is the parent root module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './auth/signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './auth/signup/signup.component';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';
import { ChildRoutingModule } from './auth/auth.route';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    //{path: '', redirectTo:'signup', pathMatch:'full'},
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},

    {path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And here is the parent module app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

import {AuthService} from './auth/auth.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './routes';
import { ChildRoutingModule } from './auth/auth.route';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ChildRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AuthModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule

  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My problem now is that when I hit the register button in the home component:

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>
<button [routerLink]="['/signup']" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
<hr>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

With no script in the home.component.ts, I will redirect to a blank component with the correct link:

> localhost:4200/signup

And with no errors at the console.

P.S.: if I typed localhost:4200/singin it will show me the sign in component normally

Comment: Sooo...AuthModule has routes, and one of those routes lazy loads the AuthModule.. which.. will have routes.. and one of those routes lazy loads the AuthModule which.... well.. you know where this is going :)

Comment: yeah, Tyler told me about the circular dependency in his answer

Comment: @PierreDuc still can't resolve it

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a circular dependency.

`AuthModule` imports the `ChildRoutingModule` that includes a `signup` route lazily-loaded to `AuthModule`.
That is why `signin` works, but `signup` does not, as `signup` is a circular dependency.

**EDIT**

To solve this, I would change up your routing a bit.  First off, I wouldn't create separate `NgModules` just to hold route configurations.  Add the route configs to the appopriate modules.  I haven't tested this exact code, but it should look something like this:

```
//app.routes.ts

import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'signin', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'},
    {path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent}
];
```

Use that in your `AppModule`:

```
// app.module.ts

import { ROUTES as appRoutes } from './app.routes';

...

imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
],
```

Then do a similar thing for the route config for the `AuthModule`:

```
//auth.routes.ts

import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: SigninComponent},
    {path: 'signup', loadChildren: './auth.module#AuthModule'}
];
```

And Import it in your `AuthModule`:

```
//auth.module.ts

import { ROUTES as authRoutes } from './auth.routes';

imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild(authRoutes)
]
```

With this, your whole `AuthModule` is lazily loaded and your url's stay the same as you have them.

Comment: Nope. It didn't worked like you resolution, still the same behavior of mine

Comment: Then you must have another problem somewhere else besides the circular dependency.  Check your modules again and make sure your AppModule has BrowserModule (and not also CommonModule) and that your other modules import CommonModule and not BrowserModule.